# SQL Query Selection Syntax

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a table with columns Customer and job.

I have rows:

Customer 1, Job 1
Customer 1, Job 2
Customer 1, Job 3
Customer 2, Job 1
Customer 2, Job 2
Customer 2, Job 3
Customer 3, Job 1
Customer 3, Job 2
Customer 3, Job 3

I have a query:

```
Select *
from Table
Where Customer <> 'Customer 1'
  AND (Customer <> 'Customer 2' AND Job <> 'Job 1')
```

The rows I would want returned from this are:

Customer 2, Job 2
Customer 2, Job 3
Customer 3, Job 1
Customer 3, Job 2
Customer 3, Job 3

But instead the rows returned are only for Customer 3 jobs 2 and 3. I want to still include Customer 2 with jobs 2 and 3 and Customer 3 Job 1.

There are a lot more columns than this in the database but these where the ones in question so I only included these. The rows actually store ticket data in them. I want the customer to be able to filter out what tickets show up in reports and they may want to exclude a customer and also exclude a job from another customer but include everything else. Customer names will be unique but job names can be duplicated across customers.

Comment: Those parenthesis are also redundant. The `WHERE` you have written is effectively `WHERE Customer NOT IN ('Customer 1','Customer 2') AND Job <> 'Job 1'`. So you exclude **all** rows where the `Customer` is either `'Customer 1'` or `'Customer 2'` as well as all rows where the value of `Job` is `'Job 1'`. I suspect that the first `AND` should be an `OR`.

Comment: Since all the criteria in your WHERE clause are AND they are all being applied.  This will never return a row where Customer = 'Customer 2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set individual Customer <-> Job exclusion clauses in your `where`, and then just do a final `not in` excluding anyone you either don't want or have an existing clause for:

```
select *
from Table
where (Customer = 'Customer 2' and Job <> 'Job 1')
    or Customer not in ('Customer 1', 'Customer 2')
```

For example of extending this, if you had a `Customer 4` and wanted to exclude `Job 2` for them:

```
select *
from tbl
where (Customer = 'Customer 2' and Job <> 'Job 1')
    or (customer = 'Customer 4' and Job <> 'Job 2') --add specific customer and job exclusion
    or Customer not in ('Customer 1', 'Customer 2', 'Customer 4') --add customer 4 here because we have a specific clause for them
```